# Repeating domain name in urls of the assets files after moving host

Tags: joomla-3.x

After migrating to a new host the site isn't quite right yet. When I look at the various files that should be loaded I noticed that the domain name was being repeated by Joomla.

Eg:

> http://domain.com/domain.com/domain.com/media/jui/js/bootstrap.min.js

What has gone wrong causing that repeat of the domain name?

Thanks,

Mat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an .htaccess file, disable it - you can rename it to htaccess.txt- and see if it fixes the issue.
You might also have to disable url rewrite in Global configuration.

And clear Joomla cache.
If you cloned the full directory of the old hosting account, then most likely you moved over also old-cached files.